# add Template to Django Oscar e-commerce framework

Tags: django, e-commerce, django-oscar

Im start using oscar e-commerce framework for django.

I setup sandbox, the backend part works prefectly out of the box. 
Now i want to change the default theme to a bootstrap template that i found.

Is there is any simple way to do such things on oscar?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is! 
And there's [documentation!](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/how_to_customise_templates.html)

**TLDR**

- Add your template directory in your `TEMPLATES` settings.
- create `base.html` in your directory

Hope this helps!